Identify this PC Puzzle game I played as a child?
Platform(s): I played this on Windows, probably 97 or XP
Genre: Point and click puzzle game
Estimated year of release: Definitely before 2008, probably before 2005, I would estimate late 90s- mid 2000s.
Graphics/art style: The setting was surreal and I believe based in a dreamlike version of a stately house. It definitely had a black and white tiled floor at one point, and features like a big staircase. It think it was set within a house. I THINK it had that early 2000s skeuomorphic style where objects are quite highly rendered , with features like very dark shadows. It definitely had very dark shadows and was a little spooky because of the graphics style. But this was not a first person game like Myst, it was static scenes assembled from assets in a realistic art style that you clicked between.
Notable characters: I THINK it had a pantheon of characters based on abstract concepts, eg Luck, Time, Memory, something like that
Notable gameplay mechanics: This was a puzzle game but I can't remember the nature of the puzzles, possibly logic/ physics based puzzles eg get the right amount of water in a beaker. One game was definitily to do with objects bouncing or being thrown and you having to click them, this was the only one I could do.
Other details: I was a young child when I played this so my memory is very dreamlike itself, and any of the info I give might not be accurate to the game. I think the purpose of the game was to find and solve the puzzles of this pantheon of characters. It was very abstract and very dreamlike, it did not have a traditional narrative with a protagonist. I believe that part of the Luck mechanic was that a little shamrock or something would jump up every now and then in different parts of the game and you had to click on it in time. That was the only character I think I got anywhere with because I found the puzzles too difficult and I couldn't even navigate the game - I think this was quite hard actually and part of the puzzling, moving from one screen to another. I think the game was difficult, and I remember it having an intelligent atmosphere with strange witty dialogue. My memory is of the vibe of this game, a female queenlike character, and objects bouncing up and down that you had to click on.

Would the Arqade be a better home for this question?

@DanDan面 They only accept identification questions with images.

You can also try r/tipofmyjoystick

The question is off-topic here, but it could be "The 11th Hour".  https://www.mobygames.com/game/567/the-11th-hour/screenshots/macintosh/858828/.

@FlorianF That's not it, but thank you, you've inspired me to look at DOS games and games made earlier than 1995
